# In R, replace "\n" (The end-line) with "\" and a "n" (not the end-line) in variable

Tags: r

In a variable I try to replace the "\n" (end-line) with the characters "" and "n".
All this to get a variable where the end-line is replaced by the text "\n" literally.

I tried:

```
MyText <- gsub("\n", " \\n ", "Line1\nLine2")
```

But somehow I end up with: "Line1nLine2"
As soon I try to replace the end-line I'm not able to get the character "" in my variable.

Tried with str_replace_all, it's the same !

Has anybody an idea ?

Cheers,
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow seems to replace the slashes as well ;)

A regex in R usually needs to be escaped twice. For a fixed string, we still need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
gsub("\n", " \\\\n ", "Line1\nLine2")

gsub("\n", " \\n ", "Line1\nLine2", fixed = T)
```

###### Viewing output

It might appear that we now have two backslashes, but that's just `print()` escaping it for us:

```
> gsub("\n", " \\\\n ", "Line1\nLine2")
[1] "Line1 \\n Line2"
```

```
> test <- gsub("\n", " \\\\n ", "Line1\nLine2")
> cat(test)
Line1 \n Line2
```

```
> strsplit(test,'')
[[1]]
 [1] "L"  "i"  "n"  "e"  "1"  " "  "\\" "n"  " "  "L"  "i"  "n"  "e"  "2"
```

###### More information

... can be found for instance on the [stringr regex vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) in the paragraph `Escaping`.

Comment: Yes, nobody like my slashes !
So tried the double escape but I missed the magic part: ", fixed = T".
Now it works perfectly as intended !

Thanks you very much for your help,
E

Answer (score 1):

We could use `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub("\n", " \n ", "Line1\nLine2", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "Line1 \n Line2"
```

or without using the escape on replacement

```
gsub("\n", " \n ", "Line1\nLine2")
[1] "Line1 \n Line2"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work; a real backslash would be escaped with another backslash when printed like this. And when viewing the string character-by-character with `strsplit()` or with `charToRaw()`, it's obvious there's still a newline in there.